# Как объединить несколько выборок в одно представление SQL

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте, у меня сложилась такая ситуация, нужно к основной выборке по таблице players добавить еще одну выборку с другой таблицы (statisticsTable). Суть в том, что у игрока много статистик за каждую игру, и мне нужно вывести дополнительные столбцы в суммами по нескольким полям. примерно так

```
select sum(StatisticsTable.Falls) as 'Фолов за всю жизнь'
from StatisticsTable, Players
where (Players.PlayerID = StatisticsTable.PlayerID)
```

сам запрос для первой таблицы выглядит вот так

```
select Players.FirstName as 'Имя', 
       Countries.NationalityName as 'Национальность', 
       Teams.TeamName as 'Команда',
       Positions.PositionName as 'Позиция',
       datepart(year,getdate())-datepart(year, Convert(Varchar, DateOfBurn, 104)) as 'Возраст'
from Players, Countries, Positions, Teams
where ((Players.CountryID = Countries.CountryID) and (Players.TeamID = Teams.TeamID) and (Players.PositionID = Positions.PositionID))
```

Но просто поставить `UNION` между этими запросами приводит к ошибке 
"Сообщение 205, уровень 16,
Все запросы, объединенные с помощью операторов `UNION`, `INTERSECT` или `EXCEPT`, должны иметь одинаковое число выражений в целевых списках.
"
Помогите пожалуйста грамотно объединить эти 2 выборки

Comment: Пока не очень понятно, какие запросы объединяете. Вы объединяете два запроса, представленных в вопросе? Или два последних похожих запроса?

Comment: Совершенно не понимаю, зачем вы задаете вопросы, если даже коментарии под старыми своими вопросами не читаете (или полностью игнорируете). Я у вас пытался узнать зачем вы приводите дату к строке при вычислении возраста, а вы повторяете в этом запросе ту же ошибку ... вообще возраст было бы правильнее получать как `datediff(year, DateOfBurn, getdate())`

Comment: Я же указал ссылку в прошлом вопросе на предыдущий вопрос, где ответом было преобразование в строку, а datediff(year, DateOfBurn, getdate()) вернет где-то 1904 (если дата рождения равна 1997) т.к. я не в формате datetime храню, а просто date

Comment: + Мне показалось, что тот вопрос уже не актуален, я читал все комментарии, но мне казалось, что я все изложил в своем вопросе.

Comment: Т.е. вы храните именно год рождения, т.е. число 1997 ? Или все таки тип данных именно date и в нем лежит полный день рождения ? В первом случае вам надо тупо делать `datepart(year,getdate())-1997`, во втором отлично отработает то что я написал выше

Comment: Точно! Я не знаю что я делал до этого не так (потому что я пробовал ваш вариант самым первым, видимо, чего-то не досмотрел) но теперь все работает с datediff(year, DateOfBurn, getdate()). DOB я храню как date, не числом. Но самое интересно, что MS SQL при попытке сохранить таблицу с новым вычисляемым столбцом говорит, что ошибка в формуле вычисления Age. Но сохранение проходит, и теперь все работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

union, который вы пытаетесь применить, используется для получения дополнительных строк в выборке, а не дополнительных столбцов. А все строки разумеется должны иметь одинаковое количество столбцов.

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите получить столбец где будет сумма некоей статистики по каждому игроку (почему в приведенном первым запросе нет group by не представляю, он вам давал сумму по всем игрокам, что при запросе в разрезе игроков как то странно).

```
select Players.FirstName as 'Имя', 
       Countries.NationalityName as 'Национальность', 
       Teams.TeamName as 'Команда',
       Positions.PositionName as 'Позиция',
       datepart(year,getdate())-datepart(year, Convert(Varchar, DateOfBurn, 104)) as 'Возраст',
       (select sum(StatisticsTable.Falls)
          from StatisticsTable
         where (Players.PlayerID = StatisticsTable.PlayerID)
       )  as 'Фолов за всю жизнь'
from Players, Countries, Positions, Teams
where ((Players.CountryID = Countries.CountryID) and (Players.TeamID = Teams.TeamID) and (Players.PositionID = Positions.PositionID))
```

Если надо выбрать много колонок из таблицы статистики, то лучше переписать запрос так:

```
select Players.FirstName as 'Имя', 
       Countries.NationalityName as 'Национальность', 
       Teams.TeamName as 'Команда',
       Positions.PositionName as 'Позиция',
       datepart(year,getdate())-datepart(year, Convert(Varchar, DateOfBurn, 104)) as 'Возраст',
       Stat.Falls as 'Фолов за всю жизнь',
       Stat.xyz as 'Еще какая то статистика'
from Players, Countries, Positions, Teams,
     (select PlayerID, sum(StatisticsTable.Falls) as Falls, sum(xyz) as xyz
        from StatisticsTable
       group by PlayerID
     ) Stat
where Players.CountryID = Countries.CountryID and Players.TeamID = Teams.TeamID
  and Players.PositionID = Positions.PositionID
  and Players.PlayerID = Stat.PlayerID
```

Comment: Да, спасибо огромное, мне даже не пришло в голову так поступить

Comment: Только вот еще 1 вопрос, судя по вашему запросу, то я делаю выборку по таблице statistics, и после запроса получаю 1 столбец. Получается для если мне еще нужно 1 поле, то придется сделать еще 1 запрос, а полей мне нужно вычислить около 10. Таким же образом мне придется 10 раз делать выборку из той таблицы, это выглядит как-то не экономно по времени. Можно ли оптимизировать запрос?

Comment: Я не думал, что ответ может содержать повторную выборку для каждого столбца, поэтому указал, что нужно только 1, для компактности. Вышло плохо :(

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!